# cleaning a messy character column in R

Tags: r, replace, gsub, string-substitution

I have a column as follows.

```
 Id      Feedback
 1        c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No")
 2        c("No", "No", "No")
 3        c("No", "No", "No", "No", "Taking Medication")
```

I am trying to get rid of the No such that the final results after cleanup should look like this

```
 Id      Feedback
 1        
 2        
 3        "Taking Medication"
```

I tried using function `sub` it did not work. I tied using `gsub` the function worked but the results are messy. When I use `df1$Feedback  = gsub("No", "", df1$Feedback)` the results are like this below

```
 Id      Feedback
 1        c("", "", "", "", "", "")
 2        c("", "", "")
 3        c("", "", "", "", "Taking Medication")
```

Any help regarding this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: How did you created the `Feedback` column.  Could you show the `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata,3)))`?

Comment: Without knowing the structure, it is difficult to suggest a solution.  Perhaps `library(stringr);str_extract(df1$Feedback, 'Taking Medication')#[1] NA                  NA                  "Taking Medication"`

Comment: @akrun there's a sample of my dataset `test1 = structure (list(iD =c(1L), Feedback = c("c(\"No\", \"No\",\"No\", \"No\",\"No\", \"No\",)")))
test1 = as.data.frame(test1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We split the 'Feedback' column by 'No' or (`|`) quote (`"`).  The output is a `list`.  We loop through the `list` with `vapply`,  `grep` to get the numeric index of elements that are alphabets or space from start to end of the string (`^[A-Za-z ]$`).  We create a logical condition, i.e. `if` the `length` of the index is greater than 0, we return the element corresponding to 'x1' or `else` return `NA`.

```
df1$Feedback <-  vapply(strsplit(df1$Feedback, 'No|"'), function(x) {
                        x1 <- grep('^[A-Za-z ]+$', x)
                        if(length(x1)>0) x[x1]
                        else ''}, character(1)) 
df1
#  Id          Feedback
#1  1                  
#2  2                  
#3  3 Taking Medication
```

---

Or another option is `gsub`.  We match the substring 'No' or (`|`) double quotes, comma, parentheses (`[",()]`) or (`|`) letter 'c' followed by parentheses (`c(?:\\()`) and replace it with `''`.  The leading/lagging spaces can be removed using a second `gsub`.

```
gsub('^\\s*|\\s*$', '', 
    gsub('No|[",()]|c(?:\\()', '', df1$Feedback, perl=TRUE))
#[1] ""                  ""                  "Taking Medication"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = 1:3, 
Feedback = c("c(\"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\")", 
"c(\"No\", \"No\", \"No\")", "c(\"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"Taking Medication\")"
)), .Names = c("Id", "Feedback"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: @legrandlatoya Thanks for the feedback and encouraging words.  Glad to know that it works.

Answer (score -2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 

your_data_frame %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  do(.$Feedback %>% 
           parse(text = .) %>% 
           eval %>%
           {data_frame(Feedback = .)}) %>%
  filter(Feedback != "No")
```

Comment: I am seeing an error `Error in rep(1:nrow(data), n): invalid 'times' argument` here's a snippet of my dataset `test1 = structure (list(iD =c(1L), Feedback = c("c(\"No\", \"No\",\"No\", \"No\",\"No\", \"No\",)"))) test1 = as.data.frame(test1)`

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you had a list variable didn't realize it was a string.

Comment: no problem bud, I get an error saying ` "No"` not found

Comment: Huh, the code seems to work on the sample data in akrun's answer on my end.